# Verificando se os inputs estão vazios com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, data

Tenho o código abaixo que cria três campos no *HTML* esses campos passam pelas verificações abaixo com *JavaScript*, porém, a parte que deveria verificar se a pessoa digitou algo não funciona, estou fazendo da maneira correta?

```js
function checadatas(){
    var form_ins = document.acess;
    console.log(form_ins);
    var data1 = new Date(form_ins.inp.value);
    var data2 = new Date(form_ins.fip.value);
    if (!data1 || !data2){
      return false;
    }
    if (data1 > data2){
      alert("Data não pode ser maior que a data final");
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
    if(document.acess.inp.value == null){
            alert("Digite uma data!");
            return(false);
        } else if(document.acess.fip.value == null){
            alert("Digite uma data!");
            return(false);
        } else if(document.acess.ver.value == null){
            alert("Digite uma data!");
            return(false);
        } else {
          return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="#" onSubmit="return checadatas()" name="acess">
<br><br>
<a a class="arib">Data de inicio da verificação: </a><input type="date" name="inp"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a a class="arib">Data de fim da verificação: </a><input type="date" name="fip"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br><br><br>
<a a class="arib">Data ser realizada a verificação: </a><input type="date" name="ver"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br><br><br>
       <button class="css_btn_class" type="submit" name="Enviar">Inserir ativo</button>
</form>
```

Comment: porque o campo tem o conteúdo que pode não ser `null`, você pode comparar com vazio: `document.acess.inp.value == ""`

Comment: Fiz essa troca, e o programa continua ignorando essa parte

Comment: olha bem seu código me parece que seria correto colocar os comandos `if` que validam se está vazio no começo da *function*. 
Veja que se o campo estiver vazio, poderá dar erro nessa linha: `var `data1 = new Date(form_ins.inp.value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dois problemas:

Esses dois `return`s está impedindo do restante da função ser executada. Na verdade o que eu deixei comentado não é necessário, porque você quer fazer apenas a validação negativa:

```
if (data1 > data2){
  alert("Data não pode ser maior que a data final");
  return false;
} else {
  // return true;
}
```

O outro são as comparações com `null`:

```
document.acess.inp.value == null
```

Os valores dos campos não são null quando estão vazios. Você pode verificar desta forma:

```
!document.acess.inp.value // se for vazio, é false
```

Outro ponto é que você não precisa retornar `true` ao final da função. Caso a função não retorne nenhum `false`, nada impedirá do `submit` proceder.

**Código com correções:**

```
function checadatas(){
    var form_ins = document.acess;
    console.log(form_ins);
    var data1 = new Date(form_ins.inp.value);
    var data2 = new Date(form_ins.fip.value);
    if (!data1 || !data2){
      return false;
    }
    if (data1 > data2){
      alert("Data não pode ser maior que a data final");
      return false;
//    } else {
//      return true;
    }
    if(!document.acess.inp.value){
            alert("Digite uma data!");
            return false;
     } else if(!document.acess.fip.value){
         alert("Digite uma data!");
         return false;
     } else if(!document.acess.ver.value){
         alert("Digite uma data!");
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Tinha feito conforme um comentário acima `document.acess.inp.value == ""` e havia funcionado, mas achei o jeito que vc sugeriu mais pratico,  e realmente era o return que tava travando o método, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Você está checando `document.acess.inp.value` depois do metodo já ter terminado, "Como assim?"-Simples, no if antes do check se é igual a null, você executa um `return` não importa se `data1 > ou < a data2`, a chamada para `return` finaliza a chamada do metodo. Para corrigir, acredito que seja nescessário colocar o ultimo `if` antes de tudo no metodo.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, não havia me atentado, muito obrigado!